# Reshape2 dcast with multiple columns in R

Tags: r, reshape2, dcast

I am trying to use the dcast function in R on a dataframe but I see something is weird in my output.

[image: Original Dataframe]

```
x <- dcast(DT,COUNTRY + DESCRIPTION ~ DATE + MACRO_ECONOMIC_FACTOR_VALUE)
```

Output-

[image: x]

Instead of MACRO_ECONOMIC_FACTOR_VALUE value I see 0 and 1 and the column headers also is a concatenation of DATE and MACRO_ECONOMIC_FACTOR_VALUE

Comment: The way your code is written, the two variables on the right hand side of the formula will become columns. You probably don't want that for the economic factor value since it is not discrete categories. You probably want to use that column as the `value.var` argument to `dcast` (though I can't say for sure unless you give us an example of your desired output).

Comment: x <- dcast(DT,MNEMONIC+COUNTRY+DESCRIPTION~DATE,value.var = 'MACRO_ECONOMIC_FACTOR_VALUE',fun.aggregate = mean)
 solved it